# cannot get nativescript-plugin-firebase demo-push app to work

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Can anyone help me install the nativescript-plugin-firebase Push-demo application.  I could not manage to install and make it work. So please is there a guidance step by step for beginners?
This is the demo link:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/tree/master/demo-push

@Eddy Verbruggen: Your help will be appraciated

Regards

Comment: There is a markdown document describing the setup steps needed https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/NON_FIREBASE_MESSAGING.md

Comment: I would advise also going through the main README document https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

Comment: @Nick lliev: Thanks for your reply. But I know the links you sent me. And My problem is how to make push notification demo work 

(so that I understand how to include later this plugin in any other app to make it receive push notifications). So please I need a step by step guidance to run Push Notification demo only on Android (not interested in iOS), and do not need links to plugin docs.

Comment: So here are the steps to follow and I do not know if I am right:

- step 1:
clone "https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase.git" then "cd" to nativescript-plugin-firebase folder.

- step 2: 
should I "cd" to 'src' and execute "npm install"?
or should I run 'npm install' from the root folder which is "nativescript-plugin-firebase"?
or should I "cd" to "demo-push" (since I am interested in Push Notifications) and run 'npm install'?

Comment: Also you can check Kinvey if you want to try push notifications. https://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/push

Comment: the `demo-push` is actually a demo that shows how to work with external notification service (not Firebase console) - I've haven't played with that demo but if you need the Firebase console notifications you could directly start the base `demo` app. You will need an account in Firebase console and from then just follow the steps in the documents to create your own app. Here are some examples for apps that have implemented notifications based on the plugin's README https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos and this one (not updated to latest) https://github.com/NickIliev/TNSPushTest

Comment: @Nic lliev: thanks but alreay created my app under firebase console and used the right package id. All those steps done.

Comment: @Bascar: does Kinvey use Firebase Cloud Messaging (since GCM is deprecated)?

Comment: In fact we need Psh notification in the following scenario: the user connects to the webserver with his account, then some displays / monitors (android devices) connect and subscribe to get Push messages which are most of the time images, or text with image content...etc does the use of Nativescript with firebase push allow this?

Comment: Of course it's possible but Firebase by default shows simple notifications only. There are several types of notifications supported in Android platform, I believe you are looking for BigPictureStyle (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle). You will have to send a data only notification, so your message callback will be called as soon the devices receives an notification, then you may build the Notification yourself with examples from Android docs.

Comment: Refer the NativeScript docs here for accessing native apis in JavaScript - https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js.

Comment: @Manoj: so you mean the Firebase (FCM) with Nativescript allows the scenario I mentioned above. So with BigPictureStyle , I only send only data (just text) Push Notification from Server to registered android displays/monitors. And once the notification received by the clients (android displays) then the image copntent is called via message callback using  BigPictureStyle . Is this right?

Comment: @Nick Iliev: I managed to run an example similar to TNSPushTest (https://github.com/NickIliev/TNSPushTest). The problem I am facing is that when I send notification via POSTMAN I receive success result in POSTMAN but I am not getting any message in the android device. Normally I am supposed to receive a Pushed message on my connected android device as it is Pushed via POSTMAN. Is is right? So if this is the case than what can be the error? or Am I missing any step?

Comment: I meant firebase only supports simple notification by default and it's not a limitation on Nativescript side. When you want customized notification, like one with picture, you will have to send a data message instead of notification (refer firebase docs for more info), when received on device you will download the picture, build notification with that on your own.

Comment: @Manoj: via Firebase FCM you can Push Data Message instead of Simple Text, this data contains info like Image URL, then later using BigPictureStyle I download the image. So if this is right? Is it possible to program such client android app (to receive notification data sent via Web) with nativescript? or should I use instead Java to program it? I need the content (image or possible any other content type later) to be pushed and showed on the device once received. Think for example of the Monitors / android displays in shops showing ads. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When you send data message, the message received callback will be called, in that you will have to use the native java apis to invoke notification.  If you are not familiar with that, you may try the local notification plugin (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications) to build your notification.

Comment: @Manoj: you are helping a lot thanks so pls bear my questions. I am confused now, so what is the difference between "NativeScript Local Notifications Plugin"
 and "nativescript-plugin-firebase"'? and should I or is it better to use Java instead of Nativescript to implement the client app that will receive images as notification?

Comment: FCM is usually triggered by your backend. Local notification plugin is used to generate notification locally. FCM does nothing but transmits data in background and let's your app know that there is a message from server. In case of a simple notification, FCM uses nothing but the same code used in local notification to build a notification and display on status bar. Since you like to show image notification, and considering you are not familiar android apis, I asked you to use local notification plugin in your message received call back in order to build a notification with image using just JS.

Comment: @Manoj: the scenario is:  (1) user logs in within web application (hosted on a webserver) and sees the connected remote Displays / Monitors (having android systems), then pushes new content (image or any other content) to all displays or some of them depending on location or any other criteria. (2) the clients (android monitors / displays) subscribe to the push service and authenticate (via tokens or anything) then show always last content pushed automatically in full screen without user intervention. Web application user is informed about success or failure delivery.

Comment: @Manoj: so is it better in the above mentioned scenario to use Java with FCM notification? or is it enough to use Nativescript? and does Local native script notification suit for the scenario in which content is pushed from a web application (to which multiple users log in with their accounts) and the display occurs on another android app installed on each display, and each display registers to a specific user with the token provided by this user?